# How to correctly way to use onSnapshot of firebase firestore in Vuex4?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuex

I try to use firebase firestore in my latest vue3.js webapps.
I have used vuex4 as sate management in my apps.
My apps also use firebase authentication as login, logout, and make new users.

My apps use `snapShot` function after login,
but an error occurred like below.

```
Uncaught Error in snapshot listener: FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.
```

But I have made the code unsubscribe `onSnapshot` function after logout event.
My code is like below:

store/index.js

```
const store = createStore({
 state: {
  unsubscribe: null,
 },
 actions: {
  startListner(context) {
   context.state.unsubscribe = onSnapshot(
      //something result get proccess
   )
  },
  stopPostsListner(context) {
      context.state.unsubscribe();
    },
 }
})
```

I made `onSnapshot` function as vuex actions methods.
And then use these functions at index.vue.

index.vue

```
<script setup>
import { useStore } from "vuex";
import { onMounted, onUnmounted } from "vue";
const store = useStore();

onMounted(() => {
  store.dispatch("startPostsListner");
});
onUnmounted(() => {
  store.dispatch("stopPostsListner");
});
</script>
```

I thought `onSnapshot` function unsubscribe after destroying the component, but errors keep occurring.

How correctly way to use `onSnapshot` in vuex4?

Comment: From firestore security rules. Can you please change `allow read, write: if` **false;** to **true;** and check if you are still getting this error?

Comment: Thanks for comments. I checked firestore rules and change allow, no errors keep occurring again, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Posting my comment as an answer for better visibility.*

From the security rules by changing:

```
allow read, write: if
```

from `false;` to `true;` will help to fix the error.